# Maven build jar file with Class-Path included in MANIFEST.MF cannot resolve library classes

Tags: maven, neo4j, classpath

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.doop</groupId>
    <artifactId>donkey</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
          <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
          <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-neo4j-driver</id>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <includeArtifactIds>neo4j-java-driver</includeArtifactIds>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.doop.server.ServerApplication</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <target>11</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I `mvn clean install` it builds successfully. But when I `java -jar .\target\donkey-1.0.jar` it shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/driver/AuthTokens
        at com.doop.server.ServerApplication.<init>(ServerApplication.java:30)
        at com.doop.server.ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.driver.AuthTokens
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 2 more
```

When I unpack my donkey*.jar and look at the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Class-Path: gson-2.8.9.jar neo4j-java-driver-5.5.0.jar reactive-streams-
 1.0.4.jar netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar 
 netty-resolver-4.1.87.Final.jar netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar netty-tra
 nsport-4.1.87.Final.jar netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.87.Final
 .jar netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar netty-tcnative-classes-2.0.56.Final.j

<SUPER LONG LIST, WON'T BORE YOU WITH IT>

 notations-2.14.1.jar jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar txw2-2.3.2.jar istack-commo
 ns-runtime-3.0.8.jar stax-ex-1.8.1.jar FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar jakarta.a
 ctivation-api-1.2.1.jar jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar neo4j-capabiliti
 es-5.5.0.jar
Main-Class: com.doop.server.ServerApplication
```

the Main-Class exists in the jar file under :com/doop/server/ServerApplication.class.
Although the Class-Path is present in the MANIFEST.MF there are no 3rd party libraries in the jar file, just my class files (and the manifest).

Comment: UPDATE: when I go into target\classes and execute `java com.doop.server.ServerApplication` it throws the error ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/driver/AuthTokens
        at com.doop.server.ServerApplication.<init>(ServerApplication.java:30)
        at com.doop.server.ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.driver.AuthTokens
        ... 2 more``` but then I add the neo4j jar to the classpath and it can no longer find the ServerApplication!?!?!?!

Comment: When I make the `ServerApplication main(...) { System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")); }` and run `java -classpath .\target\classes com...ServerApplication` it says ```.\target\classes\```. But if I say `java -classpath .\target\:$Env:CLASSPATH com....ServerApplication` it says ```Error: Could not find or load main class com.dereOida.server.ServerApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dereOida.server.ServerApplication```

Comment: My windows 10 system environment variable CLASSPATH is set to "\Users\<my username>\.m2\respository". It seems as soon as I include that in the java command it cannot find my ServerApplication class. I have deleted the com\doop folder in the repository to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the JARs packed into your JAR, you need to use Maven Assembly Plugin or Maven Shade Plugin.